# Conserved current from the three $SU(2)$ transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem

We are asked to show that the following Lagrangian is invariant under the three $SU(2)$ transformations $\Phi \rightarrow \exp{({\frac{i}{2}{\alpha_j\sigma^j}}) \Phi}$, where $\Phi$ is a doublet complex scalar field$$\Phi =( \phi_1 \phi_2)^{T}$$
The given Lagrangian is

$$
\mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu\Phi^{\dagger}\partial_\mu\Phi-m^2\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi 
$$

I have re-written the Lagrangian as

$$
\mathcal{L} = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu{\phi_i}^\dagger\partial_\nu{\phi_i}-m^2\phi^{\dagger}_i\phi_i
$$

Where $i = 1,2$.

I derived $\delta\mathcal{L}=0$ using the fact that $\vec{\sigma}_j = \vec{\sigma}_j^\dagger$. My problem is finding $\delta\phi_i$ and $\delta\phi_i^\dagger$. How can I expand the exponential? And also, will I get 3 conserved currents for each complex field?

How would I calculate $$\alpha_j(j^\mu)_i = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial({\partial_\mu\phi_i})}\delta\phi_i+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial({\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger_i})}\delta\phi^\dagger_i$$

Edit 1:

Attempting to calculate $\delta\phi_i$ I expand the exponential to linear order since the parameter $\alpha_j \ll 1$. Hence $\delta\phi_i= I + i\alpha_j\sigma^j$. Assuming this is true, how does that summation look like? Would each j have a different charge?

Comment: That was very helpful! I have edited the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have used $\alpha$ for both the transformation parameter and the index of the fields. Does this edit make my question valid now ?

Comment: Yes.                   ..."..."...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding the notation.
$$
\delta \Phi =  \exp{({\frac{i}{2}{\alpha_j\sigma^j}}) \Phi} -\Phi  +O(\alpha^2)= \frac{i}{2}\alpha_j\sigma^j \Phi,
$$
so that 
$$
\delta  \begin{pmatrix}
      \phi_1\\
      \phi_2
    \end{pmatrix}  = \frac{i}{2}   \begin{pmatrix}
      \alpha_3&\alpha_1-i\alpha_2\\
      \alpha_1+i\alpha_2&-\alpha_3
    \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
      \phi_1\\
      \phi_2
    \end{pmatrix}  ,
$$
which you may perform to get $\delta\phi_j$.

Now 
$$
\frac{i}{2} \alpha_j ~ (\partial^\mu \Phi^\dagger \sigma^j \Phi - \Phi^\dagger \sigma^j \partial^\mu \Phi) 
$$
 represents three currents, an SU(2) adjoint triplet, the coefficients of the three parameters $\alpha_j$, normally omitted. Did you compute them? Indeed, integrating their zero components produces three isocharges, closing into an su(2) Lie algebra.